# Change the style of CSS several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a chat and I have issue with the jQuery part.

```
<ul id="buttomIcon">
    <li id="span1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send iconCom"></span></li>
</ul>
```

So I want that when I click on the icon it opens up the chat windows

```
<div class="container closeAll">
    <div class="row display chatBox drag ">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-9 ">
            <div class="dragIt ">
                <button class="close closeChat" data-dismiss="drag"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove closeChat"></span></button>
            </div>
            <iframe class=""></iframe>
            <textarea class="" id="chat"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I click on the icon-remove it close the chat window.

But the issue is when I want to try again and open it, it does't work any more. and here is my jQuery:

```
$("#span1 span").click(function () {
    $(".chatBox").toggle();
});

$(".closeChat").click(function () {
    $(".closeAll").hide();
});
```

Comment: if you click on that twice then does it open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$("#span1 span").click(function () {
            $(".chatBox").toggle();
            $(".closeAll").show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's working, but with bugs i would say:

```
$("#span1 span").click(function () {
    $(".chatBox").toggle();
});
$(".closeChat").click(function () {
    $(".closeAll").hide();
});
```

check above what you have done:

1. You have a click event on `$("#span1 span")` and you are toggling `$(".chatBox")`.
2. You have another click event on `$(".closeChat")` and this is hiding the parent element `$(".closeAll")` which has `$(".chatBox")`.

---

So use this:

```
$(".chatBox").toggle();  
$(".closeAll").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In other solutions, if you hide `.closeAll`, you need to click twice on the `.chatBox` to reopen chatBox. for this below is the solution

Try as below:

```
$("#span1 span").click(function () {
     $(".chatBox").toggle();
});

$(".closeChat").click(function () {
     $(".chatBox").toggle();
});
```